# Asking for PACKAGE_USER_STATS authorization

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to ask an authorization for devices with API >= 23 to check package user stats.
As stated in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#System, I can use the android.app.usage API.

The usage of that API requires that I declare in the manifest this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"  />
```

But if I don't "ignore ProtectedPermissions", AndroidStudio gives me this error:

[image]

The questions:

- does this mean that, how stated in the documentation, *The user must also enable access for this app through Settings > Security > Apps with usage access.*, or the two things are not related to eachothers?
- How do I ask to the user *to enable access for this app through Settings > Security > Apps with usage access.* anyway?
- And anyway, why, when I manually set to *on* the app in *Settings > Security > Apps*, bypassing the previous point, I still don't get the dialog when I reach this lines of code, the authorization still is not given? This is exactly what the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#System) seems to ask to do. Why this request doesn't even popup? What else is missing?

  ```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(myActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);  // <-- I reach this point but the dialog does not popup!??
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You should set permission like that;

```
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

And you can access permission as below;

```
   Intent intent = new 
   Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
             startActivity(intent);
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Note that for tools:ignore, you will need to import another XML namespace, or else you will get ANOTHER error. The correct XML namespace is as follows:

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Add it to the `manifest` tag that is the root of the XML document.

Alternatively, Android Studio has a shortcut that you can click on to suppress the original error about protected permissions. It does all of the above for you, automatically.